# Tools to log and analyse a toddlers diet

Tags: allergies, diet

I am looking for a tool I can use to work out what is causing my son to vomit. It's happening during or after eating so I assume a connection to what was eaten.

I need to:

Quickly log what was in each meal (Meat, soya, vegetables, additives, spices etc) at either a high level or in detail.

Log what happens. I want to log vomiting and gas and other symptoms as separate events from meals.

Combine observations from mum dad and the nursery (the nursery log a vague description on a website).

Look for correlations across different lengths of time. I don't know (don't want to assume) whether the issue is taking hours or minutes to develop.

I like the idea of an app with cloud based data sharing so we can work as a team. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any particular reasons you can't used a notebook or planner that you share? Do suggestions *need* to be app-based? If so, this may be a product-suggest question and not necessarily on topic.

Comment: I am open to paper solutions.

Comment: Look for a list of the top ten infant allergies and focus on those. one of my twins was allergic to strawberries and he would vomit hours later.

Comment: We used a notebook that went to daycare with the child in the morning. Perhaps it's time for a more systematic approach, i.e. an elimination diet, to figure out the trigger(s)? Also, if you're not yet working with a pediatrician or specialist on this, I would encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

[Trixie Tracker](http://www.trixietracker.com/) has a section for eating, as far as I can recall. You have to pay for that. It stores data online.
I don't know if it will correlate data, but you can enter observations about meals. I has been 3 years since I have used it, so you may want to double check.

[Care Zone](https://carezone.com/home) has tools for managing anyones health. It is mostly about medications and illnesses, but it has a journal for tracking. You can have a team of persons taking care of another person, or your self.

These are both journal based, and shares data. I don't know of any app/website where you have a predetermined list of checkboxes, and data correlation. For that, it might useful to have a shared spreadsheet (google docs, ms office 364 on skydrive, others)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Feed Baby (Pro)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.penguinapps.android.babyfeeding.client.android.pro) to track feeding, sleeping, diapers and so on. I find it very user-friendly, for example you tap to log what is going on now, and you hold to log an event that happend in the past.
You can just select and tap to add an event without details or add a short note.

It has cloud backup, and you can synchronize accross devices. The reporting works well enough for my needs. If you need more, you can export your data in csv-format ("comma separated values") for further analysis in Excel or R, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [Trello](https://trello.com/) to track all kinds of things. It's essentially a series of lists grouped into a board. The app (android) is great, as is the website and will allow for multiple users (Parents, grandparents, caregivers) to log in and make changes/add new entries.

As an example you could create lists for foods eaten, and if there is a reaction to that food drag that food into say a list for the symptom (gas, vomiting etc), or into a list entitled 'safe'

Each 'card' (as an entry on a list is called) can have as little or as much detail as you wish. Personally I point form whatever I need when it happens and flesh out more detail later as time permits (like when the kids are in bed)

Answer (score 1):

You could paper and a pencil. If you use a notebook, you can write exactly what you want. You can record stuff about the meal such as date, individual ingredients, beverages, amount eaten, etc. You can also record when there are incidents you think are food related, such as nausea, vomiting, diarrhea, etc. You can also have multiple notebooks, or just share one between everyone feeding your child.

If you need a little more structure, I would recommend a "meal tracker" or "food journal" notebook. There are a large variety of these, so you'd have to find one with the fields you'd like.

Personally, I'd prefer using a spreadsheet program. Many of the most popular spreadsheet programs these days have cloud integration, collaboration features, and are accessible on mobile devices.

Using a spreadsheet also gives you more control over the structure of what you record, and stores your data in a format that makes it easier for you to analyze.

You can label rows and columns so that everyone puts the same information in the same spot. You could have a separate tab/page for meals vs. incidents, and really whatever else you could want.

I won't suggest a particular product or app, but I would say spreadsheets are a really easy (and probably free) way for you to record this information easily. Most apps that record this type of information are going to be storing your data in much the same way, but making your user interface look a little more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a while before investing in the creation of any system.

It may be possible to spot the relationships after some more time and by e.g. examining the vomit. I found small undigested vegetables such as sweetcorn and raisins in the vomit and was able to then spot patterns related to those items.

In this case he pukes after his next meal if he hasn't chewed vegetables in his last meal.